# Define a missing method through AOP?

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm in a situation where the implementation of a library we are using is newer than the implementation one of our dependencies was coded against. E.g. Dependency uses MyLibrary-1.0 and we're using MyLibrary-2.0.

In the newer implementation a deprecated method has been removed, which causes run-time errors for us.

I'm trying to use AOP (Spring-AOP to be specific) to intercept calls made to the missing method, and proxy them into an existing method... but I can't seem to get the Aspect right.

It feels like Java is raising the 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' exception before my Aspect has an opportunity to intercept. Is there some trick I'm missing, or is this just not feasible (e.g. the method must exist in order to aspect it)?

```
@Before("execution(* com.mylibrary.SomeClass.*(..))") 
     Fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

@Around("target(com.mylibrary.SomeClass) && execution(* missingMethod(..))")
     Fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your are talking about a 3rd party library which is independent of Spring, you cannot use Spring AOP with its proxy-based "AOP lite" approach which only works for public, non-static methods of Spring components. Please use the more powerful AspectJ instead. The [Spring manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) explains how to integrate full AspectJ with load-time weaving (LTW) into Spring applications. If your application is not based on Spring so far and you just wanted to use the framework because of Spring AOP, you can skip the whole Spring stuff altogether and use plain AspectJ.

The feature you want to use is an inter-type declaration (ITD), more specifically AspectJ's ability to declare methods for existing classes. Here is some sample code:

**3rd party library:**

```java
package org.library;

public class Utility {
    public String toHex(int number) {
        return Integer.toHexString(number);
    }

    // Let us assume that this method was removed from the new library version
    /*
    @Deprecated
    public String toOct(int number) {
        return Integer.toOctalString(number);
    }
    */
}
```

Let us assume that the method I commented out was just removed from the latest version your own project depends on, but you know how to re-implement it.

**Project dependency depending on old version of 3rd party library:**

```java
package com.dependency;

import org.library.Utility;

public class MyDependency {
    public void doSomethingWith(int number) {
        System.out.println(number + " in octal = " + new Utility().toOct(number));
    }
}
```

Because the previously deprecated method `Utility.toOct` does not exist anymore in the version used by your own project, you will get `NoSuchMethodError` during runtime when calling `MyDependency.doSomethingWith`.

**Your own application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.library.Utility;

import com.dependency.MyDependency;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("3333 in hexadecimal = " + new Utility().toHex(3333));
        new MyDependency().doSomethingWith(987);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the application also uses the same library, but a different method which still exists in the current version. Unfortunately, it also uses the dependency which relies on the existence of the removed method. So how should we repair this?

**Aspect using ITD:**

AspectJ to the rescue! We just add the missing method to the 3rd party library.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.library.Utility;

public aspect DeprecatedMethodProvider {
    public String Utility.toOct(int number) {
        return Integer.toOctalString(number);
    }
}
```

If you compile this project with the AspectJ compiler *Ajc*, it just works. In your real life scenario, compile the aspect into its own aspect library, put the weaving agent *aspectjweaver.jar* on the JVM command line in order to activate LTW and enjoy how it weaves the method into the library class via byte code instrumentation during class-loading.

**Log output:**

```
3333 in hexadecimal = d05
987 in octal = 1733
```

Et voilà! Enjoy. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

When the JVM load a class, it resolves all dependencies in a "linker" phase : external classes, properties and method. You can't pass this phase in your case, because methods are missing.

There are two modes on (Spring-)AOP: Proxy, and weaving.

1. Proxy create... a proxy around a class: the targeted class must exist and be loaded
2. Weaving can happen before a class is loaded: when a classloader load a class, an array of byte[] is passed to the weaver, which can manipulate the class bytecode before the class is really reified. This type of aop **can** work in your case. However, it will not be an easy task.